# Power Bi dax logic

Tags: powerbi, logic, dax

I am facing an issue in my dax logic of power bi , this logic gives me the sum of data for the selected dates , for example , I have selected 6th january and 18th january from the date slicer , it will total the values between 6th and 18th January ... Below is the logic I am using in Power BI:

```
PY Sales W = 
VAR SelectedStartDate = MIN('Cal'[Date])
VAR SelectedEndDate = MAX('Cal'[Date])
VAR PreviousYearStartDate = SelectedStartDate - 364
VAR PreviousYearEndDate = SelectedEndDate - 364
RETURN
SUMX(
    VALUES('Cal'[FiscalWeek]),
    VAR WeekSales =
        CALCULATE(
            [CY Sales1],
            FILTER(
                ALL('Cal'),
                'Cal'[Date] >= PreviousYearStartDate &&
                'Cal'[Date] <= PreviousYearEndDate &&
                'Cal'[FiscalWeek] = EARLIER('Cal'[FiscalWeek]) &&
                'Cal'[IsPast] = TRUE()
            )
        )
    RETURN
    IF(ISBLANK(WeekSales), BLANK(), WeekSales)
```

`your text`
I have tried multiple solution , some are giving me blank. I am using this logic for Day to Day comparison
PY Sales = CY sales (last year)
What I am expecting in PY Sales is my previous year data on the same day

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `'Cal'[FiscalWeek] = EARLIER('Cal'[FiscalWeek]) &&` is the part causing the issue. `EARLIER` is usually used in Calculated Columns where there is row context. Do you need it? Do you want to show PY numbers based on the same (complete) FiscalWeek?

You could use [DAX Time Intelligence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax) functions and simplify it to:

```
PY Sales W = 
  CALCULATE(
    [CY Sales1],
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Cal'[Date])
  )
```

Or:

```
PY Sales W = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT('Cal'[FiscalWeek]),
    CALCULATE(
      [CY Sales1],
      SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Cal'[Date])
    )
  )
```

Comment: Hey Sam , but this is showing me date to date comparison but I want day to day comparison.